# How to make profilers (valgrind, perf, pprof) pick up / use local version of library with debugging symbols when using mpirun?

Tags: linux, profiling, shared-libraries, mpi, debug-symbols

**Edit:** *added important note that it is about debugging MPI application*

System installed shared library doesn't have debugging symbols:

```
$ readelf -S /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so | grep debug
$
```

I have therefore compiled and instaled in my home directory my owne version, with debugging enabled (`--with-debug CFLAGS=-g`):

```
$ $ readelf -S ~/lib64/libfftw3.so | grep debug
  [26] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001d3902
  [27] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001d8552
  [28] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001ddebd
  [29] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  003e221c
  [30] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00414306
  [31] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0044aa23
  [32] .debug_loc        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  004514de
  [33] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0046bc82
```

I have set both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_RUN_PATH to include `~/lib64` first, and `ldd program` confirms that local version of library should be used:

```
$ ldd a.out | grep fftw
        libfftw3.so.3 => /home/narebski/lib64/libfftw3.so.3 (0x00007f2ed9a98000)
```

The program in question is ***parallel*** numerical application using **[MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)** (Message Passing Interface).  Therefore to run this application one must use `mpirun` wrapper (e.g. `mpirun -np 1 valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out`).  I use OpenMPI implementation.

Nevertheless, various profilers: [**callgrind**](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) tool in [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/), [CPU profiling](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) [google-perfutils](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) and [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) doesn't find those debugging symbols, resulting in more or less ***useless*** output:

- calgrind:

  ```
  $ callgrind_annotate --include=~/prog/src --inclusive=no  --tree=none
  [...]
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              Ir  file:function
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  32,765,904,336  ???:0x000000000014e500 [/usr/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4]
  31,342,886,912  /home/narebski/prog/src/nonlinearity.F90:__nonlinearity_MOD_calc_nonlinearity_kxky [/home/narebski/prog/bin/a.out]
  30,288,261,120  /home/narebski/gene11/src/axpy.F90:__axpy_MOD_axpy_ij [/home/narebski/prog/bin/a.out]
  23,429,390,736  ???:0x00000000000fc5e0 [/usr/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4]
  17,851,018,186  ???:0x00000000000fdb80 [/usr/lib64/libmpi.so.1.0.1]
  ```
- google-perftools:

  ```
  $ pprof --text a.out prog.prof
  Total: 8401 samples
       842  10.0%  10.0%      842  10.0% 00007f200522d5f0
       619   7.4%  17.4%     5025  59.8% calc_nonlinearity_kxky
       517   6.2%  23.5%      517   6.2% axpy_ij
       427   5.1%  28.6%     3156  37.6% nl_to_direct_xy
       307   3.7%  32.3%     1234  14.7% nl_to_fourier_xy_1d
  ```
- perf events:

  ```
  $ perf report --sort comm,dso,symbol
  # Events: 80K cycles
  #
  # Overhead  Command         Shared Object                                        Symbol
  # ........  .......  ....................  ............................................
  #
      32.42%  a.out     libfftw3.so.3.2.4     [.]            fdc4c
      16.25%  a.out             7fddcd97bb22  [.]     7fddcd97bb22
       7.51%  a.out     libatlas.so.0.0.0     [.] ATL_dcopy_xp1yp1aXbX
       6.98%  a.out     a.out                 [.] __nonlinearity_MOD_calc_nonlinearity_kxky
       5.82%  a.out     a.out                 [.] __axpy_MOD_axpy_ij
  ```

---

**Edit** *Added 11-07-2011*:
I don't know if it is important, but:

```
$ file /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4
/usr/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

and

```
$ file ~/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4
/home/narebski/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Comment: If you use [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/) or [this method of finding time drains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) you don't need your libs to have symbols, because any problem you can fix is one or a few lines in your code, not the external librarary, and those lines are pinpointed.

Answer (score 4):

If `/usr/lib64/libfftw3.so.3.2.4` is listed in callgrind output, then your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib64` had *no effect*.

Try again with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib64`. Also watch out for any shell scripts you invoke, which might reset your environment.

Comment: You are right.  I am using `mpirun` from OpenMPI, and it does prepend `/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:` to 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' (which I checked by running `mpirun -np 1 printenv`).  I'd have to use `--prefix` or `-x` option to *mpirun*.

Answer (score 2):

You and Employed Russian are almost certainly right; the mpirun script is messing things up here.   Two options:

Most x86 MPI implementations, as a practical matter, treat just running the executable

`./a.out`

the same as

`mpirun -np 1 ./a.out`.

They don't have to do this, but OpenMPI certainly does, as does MPICH2 and IntelMPI.  So if you can do the debug serially, you should just be able to

`valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out`.

However, if you do want to run with mpirun, the issue is probably that your `~/.bashrc`
 (or whatever) is being sourced, undoing your changes to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc.   Easiest is just to temporarily put your changed environment variables in your `~/.bashrc` for the duration of the run.

Comment: No, it is not that.  It is `mpirun` adding "prefix" to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which you can check using `mpirun -np 1 printenv`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out` would profile also mpirun part, something I do not want; though I have not checked if it is much of hindrance.

Comment: prefix should only be the path to OpenMPI, which should be irrelevant (unless you put the fftw in the same place as the MPI libraries).   and `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out` won't magically call mpirun; it'll launch the a.out executable.

Comment: OpenMPI uses '/usr' prefix, and `mpirun` **prefixes** '/usr/bin' to PATH, and '/usr/lib' and '/usr/lib64' (on x86_64) to LD_LIBRARY_PATH... which means that stripped system-installed library without debugging info was used by `mpirun ... ./a.out` and not user-installed one with debugging into.

Comment: So you do have everything installed in the same place.  Not a great idea, but if you're just using whatever the package manager does for you, that'll happen; too bad.  Anyway, again, the problem can be avoided by not running mpirun, as you don't need it for 1 task.  If you don't believe me, try it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *everything in the same place*.  `mpirun` is in '/usr/bin', library is in '/usr/lib64'; common prefix is '/usr'.

Comment: The fftw and mpi libraries are all in the same place.  Anyway, all this is beside the point.  Have you tried running `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out `?

Answer (score 1):

The way recent profiling tools typically handle this situation is to consult an external, matching non-stripped version of the library.

On debian-based Linux distros this is typically done by installing the `-dbg` suffixed version of a package; on Redhat-based they are named `-debuginfo`.

In the case of the tools you mentioned above; they will typically Just Work (tm) and find the debug symbols for a library if the debug info package has been installed in the standard location.

Comment: What if distribution in question is **Gentoo** (and I am not an administrator)?

Comment: @Jakub: Certainly in the case of `perf report` you can specify an alternative location to look for debuginfo files using the `--symfs` option. You'll have to check if your other tools support a similar option.

Comment: I think I'd have to upgrade `perf` to have access to `--symfs` option; at least for 2.6.36 this option is not mentioned in documentation.